# Drooping leaves on orange tree

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, leaves, citrus

I have had an orange tree (Valencia Orange) for roughly a year now, and it is currently a 30-something inches sapling.

It so far was looking healthy, but in the past couple days, some new leaves it had been making appear to be drooping *(is wilting the right term? See picture below)*

Is it because it needs more water? (I have it indoors, in my office, and winter in New York can be quite dry. The temperature itself is never too cold, as it's indoors; and for the past week or so I have started misting the leaves 2-3 times a day with a spray filled with plain water.) Or could it be a lack of nutrients, or something else?

Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Has the window been opened recently, or is the handle/catch always in that position, that is, not fully closed?

Comment: It has been briefly opened during the day. While not entirely pushed back, putting the handle in that position almost hermetically closes the window,  however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the soil in the pot isn't bone dry and you're watering as you have been doing during  the last year, the most likely cause of the new leaves drooping is exposure to chilly air. A window that is not fully shut with the catch is not properly closed and cold air can certainly seep through, particularly overnight when, presumably, the heating is not running, or is running at a much lower level. The new growth will be  more sensitive to cold than the older growth, so if the window was opened, however briefly, the cold blast will have affected that new growth.

It may also be that that the plant now requires a little more water, as its putting out new growth and is using up more because of active growth and transpiration. Equally, if its been in the same pot for longer than a year, its possible it now requires more root room, so a bigger pot might be called for - you can check by turning it out of its pot, carefully, to see if its rootbound. Otherwise, from what I can see of the growth, it seems healthy other than the new growth wilting.

Comment: Thank you! Today was "watering day," so I added some potassium-rich "plant food" to the water beforehand (and made sure the window was fully closed). I'll wait and see what happens.

Comment: It seems to have stopped. Not sure which of the factors (water, warmth, nutrients) was the main one, but at least it's looking much better.

Comment: It won't be nutrient shortage, especially not potassium shortage, so its probably the cold/water situation its responding to.